# Solve problems from a txt or pdf file

Tags: equation-solving, import, syntax, data-acquisition

I have tried in vain to recover problems from a flat file and from a pdf and pass them through the reduce option and have it solve the exercises one by one in batches.
Any idea how to achieve it?
The only thing I can think of is this instruction in its plain text version and in its pdf version

data = ReadList["https://www.dropbox.com/s/0novhzk3u0v15ix/e1.txt?dl=0", Word,RecordLists -> True];

data = ReadList["https://www.dropbox.com/s/ayr4jzgkihsly7e/e2.pdf?dl=0", Word,RecordLists -> True];

edit

Ready
ReadList["https://drive.google.com/file/d/14GnPbm5LvANvtcOSxyFM3n9_x0VU6BIZ/view?usp=share_link", Word,RecordLists -> True];

ReadList["https://drive.google.com/file/d/1F20ABqN7Pz6ZYznsPR-e35VHqywwVexl/view?usp=share_link", Word,RecordLists -> True];

Comment: The link leads to an `Error (500)` page. Please provide a 1-click accessible link that is public.

Comment: Syed , Hello, the links work for me, but I put new links to drive,see edit

Answer (score 2):

```
(data3 = ReadList["C:/e1.txt", "String", 
    RecordLists -> True]) // TableForm

data4a = StringTrim[First /@ data3, 
  StartOfString ~~ Shortest[__] ~~ ") "]

data4 = ToExpression@data4a

res = Reduce[#, x] & /@ data4

(data5 = Join[{{"#", "expr", "sol"}}, 
    Transpose[{Range@Length@data4, data4a, res}]]) // 
 Grid[#, Spacings -> {2, 1}, Alignment -> Left] &
```

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 \# & \text{expr} & \text{sol} \\
 1 & \text{x/(x-1)$<$1 } & x<1 \\
 2 & \text{2x/(2x+1)$>$1} & x<-\frac{1}{2} \\
 3 & \text{-2x/(3-x)$<$=2} & x<3 \\
 4 & \text{-3x/(2-x)$>$=3} & x>2 \\
 5 & \text{(x+1)/(2x-1)$<$1/2} & x<\frac{1}{2} \\
 6 & \text{2x/(3x-2) $>$2/3} & x>\frac{2}{3} \\
 7 & \text{(3x-1)/(1-2x)$<$=-3/2} & x>\frac{1}{2} \\
 8 & \text{2/(1-x)$<$2} & x<0\lor x>1 \\
 9 & \text{3/(2x-1)$<$=1} & x<\frac{1}{2}\lor x\geq 2 \\
 10 & \text{1/(2x+3)$>$=1} & -\frac{3}{2}<x\leq -1 \\
 11 & \text{(2x+1)/(x+2)$<$1} & -2<x<1 \\
 12 & \text{(x-2)/(2x+3)$>$1} & -5<x<-\frac{3}{2} \\
 13 & \text{(x-2)/(2-x)$<$=1} & x\in \mathbb{R} \\
 14 & \text{(2x+1)/(2x+1)$<$=2} & \text{True} \\
 15 & \text{(2-x)/(x-1)$>$=2} & 1<x\leq \frac{4}{3} \\
 16 & \text{(2-x)/(1-2x)$<$=2} & x\leq 0\lor x>\frac{1}{2} \\
 17 & \text{(2-4x)/(2x-1) $<$=2} & x\in \mathbb{R} \\
 18 & \text{(x+2)/(x+1) $<$(x-2)/(2x+2)} & -6<x<-1 \\
 19 & \text{x / (x-2) $>$= 2 /(2x-4) } & x\leq 1\lor x>2 \\
 20 & \text{(x+2)/(x-1) +x/(2x-2)$<$=0} & -\frac{4}{3}\leq x<1 \\
 21 & \text{(x+1)/(2x+1)-1/(4x+2) $<$=1} & x\in \mathbb{R} \\
 22 & \text{1/(x-1)-1/(2x-2)$>$=1} & 1<x\leq \frac{3}{2} \\
 23 & \text{x/(x-2) -(x+1)/(2x-4) $>$=0} & x\leq 1\lor x>2 \\
 24 & \text{(x+1)/(x-1) +(2x-1)/(2x-2)$>$=1} & x\leq -\frac{3}{2}\lor x>1 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: wow , It's just what I thought, my most difficult question, it can be done from a pdf (attach one there)

Comment: I don't have the skill to extract data out of the pdf. I did try "Plaintext". Please wait and someone might provide an answer in due time.